How to handle X-Forwarded-Host & X-Forwarded-Proto to stop redirect the service to invalid host
In my scenario, when bot pass the mod header X-Forwarded-Host : anydomain.com and X-Forwarded-Proto : http then the page is redirect to anydomain.com instead to throwing a error or blocking the redirection.
I've edited my nginx.conf file and try the below changes but it is not working as it seems like the call is not reaching to that location. Here what I tried:
I have also tried this in my nginx ingress but no luck. Any help will be appericiated.
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-http2: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"

location @xyzrenderer {access_log /dev/stdout  mi_xyz_renderer_access; proxy_hide_header  Vary;set_by_lua_file $phoenix_request_id '/opt/nginx/scripts/set_request_id.lua';rewrite ^(/.+).mi $1 break;proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host "";proxy_set_header  Host  $xyzrenderer_host;proxy_set_header    Connection "";proxy_set_header  Accept-Language  $locale_id;add_header phoenix "true";add_header Edge-Cache-Tag $homepage_edge_cache_tag;add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self';";proxy_pass  $upstream_scheme://up_xyz-renderer_app;proxy_intercept_errors on;error_page 404 = @pageNotFound;}

location /mi-xyz-renderer-remote/_next/static/ {
if ($http_x_forwarded_host) {
return 403;
} if ($http_x_forwarded_proto) {
return 403;
}
rewrite /mi-xyz-renderer-remote(.*) $1 break;
try_files $uri @xyzrenderer;
}
